# Where can I update Inventory if the stock arrives in AspDotNetStorefront?

Tags: aspdotnetstorefront

I am trying to update the Inventory of a Generic Product but I found there is a option called current inventory,where I have to add the current inventory number and newly arrived stock number.Is there any way to update inventory where new stock number automatically adds with current inventory?

Answer (score 0):

Only way I can see is by adding an additional column to the bulk price import excel file which updates inventory also. You can then add the two, delete the "new inventory" column and upload.